# D3js click inside polygon

Tags: javascript, jquery, d3.js

I am drawing a simple polygon and I want to show a sort of tooltip with data when the user clicks inside the polygon

**CODE**

```
poly = [{"x":0.0, "y":25.0},
        {"x":28.5,"y":23.4},
        {"x":33.0,"y":21.0},
        {"x":39.0,"y":1.5}];

  svg.selectAll("polygon")
    .data([poly])
    .enter().append("polygon")
    .attr("points",function(d) { 
        return d.map(function(d) {
            return [scaleX(d.x),scaleY(d.y)].join(",");
        }).join(" ");
    })
    .attr("stroke","white")
    .attr("stroke-width",1)
    .attr("fill", "none")
    .attr("class", "feature")
    .on("click", function(d){ alert("HEO"); });
```

The click function is only called when clicking on one of the 4 points that defines the polygon. How can I detect a click **inside** the polygon ?

Comment: Fill this polygon with any color, and set opacity to zero.

Comment: @GerardoFurtado Better advice would be to manipulate the pointer-events property.

Comment: Indeed, better advice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the [pointer-events](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/interact.html#PointerEventsProperty) property to visible i.e. `.attr("pointer-events", "visible")` so that click events are processed even if the interior is not filled